# Creating JVM using JNI in C++ does not return

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to launch `jvm` for my server java program. Server java program internally launches another `java` process and the class/method which I am calling has `system.exist(0)`
My program works fine , it launches the required java process but program control  does not come back to c++. It just exist i.e. parent process dies.
Here is my complete code.

```
    #include <stdexcept>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <include/jni.h>

#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>


class JVMLauncherException : public std::runtime_error {
public:
    JVMLauncherException(const std::string& message) : std::runtime_error(message) 
    { 
    };
};

class Server_JVMLauncher {
public:
    Server_JVMLauncher();
    void addJars(std::string inJar);
    void LaunchJVM();
    void StartServer_Server();
    void AddServerArguments(std::string);
    void StopServer_Server();
private:
    typedef jint (JNICALL *CreateJavaVM)(JavaVM **pvm, void **penv, void *args);

    HINSTANCE     m_hDllInstance;

    std::string   m_JavaHome;
    std::string   m_ProductLibDir;
    std::string   m_JvmDllLocation;

    CreateJavaVM  m_JVMInstance;
    jclass        m_CacheServerLauncherClass;
    jmethodID     m_MainMethodID;
    JNIEnv       *m_JVMEnv;
    JavaVM       *m_RunningJVMInstance;    

    std::vector<std::string> m_listOfJars;
    std::vector<std::string> m_ServerArguments;

    void CheckForJNIException();
protected:
};

Server_JVMLauncher::Server_JVMLauncher() {
    // Check for JAVA_HOME
    char *pValue;
    size_t len;
    errno_t err = _dupenv_s( &pValue, &len, "JAVA_HOME" );
    if ( err ) {
        throw JVMLauncherException("JAVA_HOME not defined");
    }    
    m_JavaHome       = pValue;
    m_JvmDllLocation = m_JavaHome + "\\jre\\bin\\client\\jvm.dll";

    err = _dupenv_s( &pValue, &len, "Server_" );
    if ( err ) {
        throw JVMLauncherException("Server_ not defined");
    }
    m_ProductLibDir = pValue;

    m_listOfJars.push_back("dep1.jar");
    m_listOfJars.push_back("dep2.jar");
    m_listOfJars.push_back("dep3.jar");
    m_listOfJars.push_back("dep4.jar");
    m_listOfJars.push_back("dep5.jar");    
}
void Server_JVMLauncher::AddServerArguments(std::string inParam) {
    m_ServerArguments.push_back(inParam);
}
void Server_JVMLauncher::LaunchJVM() {
    // Construct the product specific class path.
    std::string strJavaClassPath = "-Djava.class.path=";
    for ( std::size_t idx = 0; idx < m_listOfJars.size() - 1 ; idx++) {
        strJavaClassPath += m_ProductLibDir + "\\lib\\" + m_listOfJars[idx] + ";";
    }
    strJavaClassPath += m_ProductLibDir + "\\lib\\" + m_listOfJars[m_listOfJars.size() - 1] ;

    // consruct java.library.path
    std::string strJavaLibraryPath =  "-Djava.library.path=";
    strJavaLibraryPath             += m_JavaHome + "\\lib" + "," + m_JavaHome + "\\jre\\lib";


    // try loading jvm dll
    m_hDllInstance = LoadLibraryA(m_JvmDllLocation.c_str());
    if( m_hDllInstance == 0) {
        throw JVMLauncherException("Cannot load jvm.dll");
    }
    m_JVMInstance = (CreateJavaVM)GetProcAddress(m_hDllInstance, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");
    if ( m_JVMInstance == NULL )  {
        throw JVMLauncherException("Cannot load jvm.dll");
    }

    JavaVMOption options[2];
    options[0].optionString  = const_cast<char*>(strJavaClassPath.c_str());
    options[1].optionString  = const_cast<char*>(strJavaLibraryPath.c_str());

    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    vm_args.version            = JNI_VERSION_1_6; //JNI Version 1.4 and above
    vm_args.options            = options;    
    vm_args.nOptions           = 2;       
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE;

    //Create the JVM

    jint res = m_JVMInstance(&m_RunningJVMInstance, (void **)&m_JVMEnv, &vm_args);
    if (res < 0)  {
        throw JVMLauncherException("Could not launch the JVM");
    }
    //m_RunningJVMInstance->AttachCurrentThread((void **)&m_JVMEnv, &vm_args);

    m_CacheServerLauncherClass = m_JVMEnv->FindClass("com/Server/internal/ServerLauncher");    
    CheckForJNIException();

    m_MainMethodID = m_JVMEnv->GetStaticMethodID(m_CacheServerLauncherClass, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    CheckForJNIException();
}

void Server_JVMLauncher::StartServer_Server() {

    if ( m_RunningJVMInstance->AttachCurrentThread((LPVOID *)&m_JVMEnv, NULL) ) {
        std::cout << "Fail to attach the current thread " << std::endl;
    }

    jclass StringClass = m_JVMEnv->FindClass("java/lang/String");
    int numOfArguments = (int)m_ServerArguments.size() + 2 ;
    int argumentIndex = 0;

    jobjectArray jargs = m_JVMEnv->NewObjectArray(numOfArguments, StringClass, NULL);    

    m_JVMEnv->SetObjectArrayElement(jargs, argumentIndex++, m_JVMEnv->NewStringUTF("start"));

    std::string strJavaClassPath = "-classpath=";
    strJavaClassPath             += "\"";
    for ( std::size_t idx = 0; idx < m_listOfJars.size() - 1 ; idx++) {
        strJavaClassPath += m_ProductLibDir + "\\lib\\" + m_listOfJars[idx] + ";";
    }
    strJavaClassPath      += m_ProductLibDir + "\\lib\\" + m_listOfJars[m_listOfJars.size() - 1] ;
    strJavaClassPath      += "\"";

    m_JVMEnv->SetObjectArrayElement(jargs, argumentIndex++, m_JVMEnv->NewStringUTF(strJavaClassPath.c_str()));

    for ( std::vector<std::string>::iterator iter = m_ServerArguments.begin(); iter != m_ServerArguments.end(); ++iter) {
        std::string argument = *iter;
        m_JVMEnv->SetObjectArrayElement(jargs, argumentIndex++, m_JVMEnv->NewStringUTF(argument.c_str()));
    }

    m_JVMEnv->CallStaticVoidMethod(m_CacheServerLauncherClass, m_MainMethodID, jargs);

    m_RunningJVMInstance->DestroyJavaVM();

    std::cout << "I am done with launching java program" << std::endl;
    CheckForJNIException();
}
void Server_JVMLauncher::StopServer_Server() {
    jclass StringClass = m_JVMEnv->FindClass("java/lang/String");
    int numOfArguments = 2 ;

    jobjectArray jargs = m_JVMEnv->NewObjectArray(numOfArguments, StringClass, NULL);    

    m_JVMEnv->SetObjectArrayElement(jargs, 0, m_JVMEnv->NewStringUTF("stop"));
    m_JVMEnv->SetObjectArrayElement(jargs, 1, m_JVMEnv->NewStringUTF("-dir=E:\\Avinash\\personal\\work\\CreateJvm\\Debug\\gfecs"));    

    m_JVMEnv->CallStaticVoidMethod(m_CacheServerLauncherClass, m_MainMethodID, jargs);
    CheckForJNIException();

}
void Server_JVMLauncher::CheckForJNIException() {
    jthrowable expt = m_JVMEnv->ExceptionOccurred();
    if (expt != NULL) {
        m_JVMEnv->ExceptionClear();
        jmethodID toString = m_JVMEnv->GetMethodID(m_JVMEnv->FindClass("java/lang/Object"), "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
        jstring estring = (jstring) m_JVMEnv->CallObjectMethod(expt, toString);
        jboolean isCopy;
        std::string message = m_JVMEnv->GetStringUTFChars(estring, &isCopy);
        throw JVMLauncherException(message);
    }
}

int main( int argc, char **argv) {
    try {
        Server_JVMLauncher instanceServer_;
      instanceServer_.LaunchJVM();
        instanceServer_.StartServer_Server();
    } catch (JVMLauncherException &excp ) {
        std::cout << excp.what() << std::endl;
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you call `CallStaticVoidMethod()` it does not create a child process but runs the Java `main()` method in the calling thread, blocking the caller until it completes. If the Java program calls `System.exit()` the process will exit immediately and will not return to the caller: **don't call `System.exit()`**.

Comment: unfortunately, I do not have access to server code. But even if the code return , I get the same result, i.e. this time I am not calling system.exit but calling "return;"

Comment: Where do you call `return` from ?

Comment: from Java main method. I have option to specify a flag, which says if the flag is true then do not call "System.exit(0)" but just "return;"

Comment: @Avinash, this worked for me as I have done this before. Sorry can't be of more help but the order of the `m_RunningJVMInstance->DestroyJavaVM();` then `CheckForJNIException()` looks odd

Comment: Thanks, but my Java Main method launches another JVM internally, which is getting started but somehow, C++ process gets exit after CallStaticVoidMethod